# Python: Convert Edgelist from NetworkX into dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, tuples, networkx

I have a weird data structure (don't know if it's a list or tuple) as a results of using Networkx. I need to convert it into a dataframe.

The 'list' I have, has the following structure:

```
[('a', 'a', {'weight': 2}),
 ('a', '!', {'weight': 0}),
 ('a', 'c', {'weight': 2}),
 ('a', 'b', {'weight': 1}),
 ('a', 'q', {'weight': 1}),
 ('a', 's', {'weight': 2}),... ]
```

and I need a dataframe as follows:

```
Inf   Prov  Weight
a        a       2
a        !       0
a        c       2
a        b       1
a        q       1
a        s       2
```

Can somebody give me hand, please?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easiest to simplify the data a bit first before creating the dataframe. 
Depending on the operation that gave you the initial data (a list of tuples, each one containing 2 strings and a dict), it may be possible to have that operation give you simplified data.  But in the case that this is not possible -- or more generally, when you don't have control over data structures generated by a given library, you can do some simple manipulations, e.g. like this:

```
import pandas as pd
# initial data from qu
raw_data = [('a', 'a', {'weight': 2}),
 ('a', '!', {'weight': 0}),
 ('a', 'c', {'weight': 2}),
 ('a', 'b', {'weight': 1}),
 ('a', 'q', {'weight': 1}),
 ('a', 's', {'weight': 2}),]

# transform data to extract the value of each weight
data = [(elem1, elem2, d_elem.get('weight', 0)) for (elem1, elem2, d_elem) in raw_data]

# put together the dataframe from the list of records
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['Inf', 'Prov', 'Weight'])
print(df)
```

gives the result as desired:

```
  Inf Prov  Weight
0   a    a       2
1   a    !       0
2   a    c       2
3   a    b       1
4   a    q       1
5   a    s       2
```

using `dict.get` allows us to specify a default value if it is not defined, rather than raising a KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
x=[('a', 'a', {'weight': 2}),
 ('a', '!', {'weight': 0}),
 ('a', 'c', {'weight': 2}),
 ('a', 'b', {'weight': 1}),
 ('a', 'q', {'weight': 1}),
 ('a', 's', {'weight': 2})]

inf_list=list([])
prov_list=list([])
weight_list=list([])

for tuple in x:
    inf_list.append(tuple[0])
    prov_list.append(tuple[1])
    weight_list.append(tuple[2])

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['inf']=inf_list
df['prov']=prov_list
df['weight']=weight_list

df['weight']=df['weight'].map(lambda x:x['weight'])

print(df)
```